# События объектов списка

Tags: c#, события, списки

Есть список, который хранит объекты, каждый из которых имеет одно и то же событие. Необходимо подписаться на это событие по каждому объекту.

```
List<ExampleObject> collection;

    foreach(var exampleObject in collection)
    {
     var thread1 = new Thread(() => exampleObject.StatusChanged += (sender, args) => SendStatusChanges(exampleObject.Id));
thread1.start();
    }

    private void SendStatusChanges(int id)
    {
    Console.write(id);
    }
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, что надо делать аргумент события и там слать id, однако, к сожалению, такой возможности нет. При описанном подходе события отрабатывают по всем объектам, но вот id, который приходит - начинает приходить всегда от последнего объекта. Как можно без добавления аргументов события решить такую задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, уберите из кода `Thread`, он там лишний.

Во-вторых, переменную цикла надо скопировать в локальную область видимости - тогда захваченная переменная не будет меняться. Ну **или** перейдите на свежую версию языка (=поставьте студию по-новее) - поведение цикла `foreach` в С# 5.0 было исправлено на более интуитивное.

Должно получится что-то вроде этого:

```
foreach(var exampleObject in collection)
{
    var exampleObjectClosure = exampleObject;
    exampleObject.StatusChanged += (s, a) => SendStatusChanges(exampleObjectClosure.Id)
}
```

Еще один вариант: если нам нужен только `Id` - можно и не запоминать весь объект

```
foreach(var exampleObject in collection)
{
    var id = exampleObject.Id;
    exampleObject.StatusChanged += (s, a) => SendStatusChanges(id)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проверить это будет возможность после выходных, но я почему-то не сомневаюсь в том, что это будет работать.

Comment: А почему Thread лишний? Данные в дальнейшем не ограничиваются методом, выводящим id. Дальше идут большие и длинные обработки, что приводит к залипанию потока.

Comment: А зачем `exampleObjectClosure`? (если мы не говорим о древних версиях языка)

Comment: @Sleeeper в таком случае вам надо **обрабатывать** событие в отдельном потоке - подписываться же на него в отдельном потоке смысла нет никакого.

Comment: @VladD у автора вопроса все симптомы древней версии языка: *"При описанном подходе события отрабатывают по всем объектам, но вот id, который приходит - начинает приходить всегда от последнего объекта."*

Comment: По поводу версии языка - Вы правы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Круто, +1 за телепатию.